# VBA: (a) Is there a different VarType() in .Net than in Office? (b) What is vbChar?

Tags: vba, vb.net, variant

In the Microsoft documentation for Office VBA, the page on the function `VarType()` lists its return values. And there is a page with a list of "VarType constants" without any explanation of what they are or where they are used, but the list is the same as the return values of `VarType()`:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/vartype-constants

In the Microsoft documentation for .Net VB, there is a page that lists values of the "VariantType Enum" and says that this ennum "Indicates the type of a variant object, returned by the VarType function.":

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.varianttype

There is a page on .Net VB functions:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/

with links to categories of functions, but none of those categories seems to include a function `VarType()`. So my first question: **Is there a function `VarType()` specific to .Net? If so, where is it documented?**

Those lists of Office and .Net `VarType()` values are almost, but not completely, the same:

|  | VariantType Enum (.Net) | VarType constants (Office) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Count of items | 20 | 19 |
| 2 | Short | vb[Integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/integer-data-type) |
| 3 | Integer [(`= vbInteger`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbinteger) | vb[Long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/long-data-type) |
| 18 | Char (`= vbChar`) | Absent |
| 20 | Long [(`= [vbLong`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vblong) | vb[LongLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longlong-data-type) |

So apparently, the function `VarType()` is subtly different in Office and .Net. And some of the constants defined for return values have the same names but different meanings in the two platforms. That seems sloppy.

I work in the Office programs, Excel and Access. I've never worked in .Net, and I suppose if I ever port VBA code from Office to .Net, I'm going to need to be careful about those differences in `VarType()` values.

In the listing of VariantType Enum values, most of the values are stated to be equivalent to a Visual Basic constant `vb...`. In the table above, I have shown those equivalences in brackets. Those constants appear to be the fields of the Constants Class:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants

That class has fields `vbInteger` and `vbLong`, and I've provided links in the table to the documentation pages on those fields. But the class does not appear to have a field, `vbChar`.

So my second question: **Does the constant `vbChar` exist? If so, what is it? Is it documented?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241323/discussion-on-question-by-newsites-vba-a-is-there-a-different-vartype-in-n).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's been a lot of criticism of my question in the comments, and I think I can piece together an answer from what I learned there. Please tell me if this answer is wrong, possibly by posting a better one.

First I will mention that one of the comments said, "You simply cannot compare [VBA and VB.net], they're apples and oranges." That is flawed logic. It's perfectly valid to compare apples and oranges. In fact, it's only if apples were the same as oranges that there would be little point in comparing them. Comparison is about recognizing differences and similarities, and that's what I was doing in my question. I can compare Latin and Greek, Fortran and C, or VBA and VB.net. Upon comparing some aspects of the latter pair, my two questions were both about VB.net (or what I called ".Net VB"). If there was something wrong with my comparison, please correct me instead of telling me not to compare them.

- (a) Is there a function `VarType()` specific to .Net? If so, where is it documented?

What I infer from the comments is that the function exists in VB.net for compatibility with other versions of VB, but is deprecated. Strangely, even though its purpose is compatibility with other version of VB and its output values are mostly the same as in VBA, some of them are different, which makes that compatibility complicated.

If there is documentation of it, nobody said where to find it.

- (b) Does the constant `vbChar` exist? If so, what is it? Is it documented?

It exists in VB.net. It is a value of the enum `VariantType`. `vbInteger` and `vbLong` are also values of that enum.

`vbInteger` and `vbLong` are also fields of the class `Constants` because they are associated with the values `VT_12` and `VT_14` of the [enum `VarEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum) (although that enum is not part of .Net). `vbChar` is not a field of the class `Constants` because it is not associated with a value of `VarEnum`.

`vbInteger` and `vbLong` have their own documentation pages as fields of the class `Constants`. `vbChar` does not have its own documentation page. Its only documentation is its appearance in the list of values of the enum `VariantType`.

Comment: VB.NET recognises everything from C because it is from the .NET library. VBA does not.

Comment: Does that have anything to do with this answer?

Comment: VB6 doesn't do chars. If you want to use them call it a byte array. Just don't expect it to work in COM. There are no strings in C only an array of characters.

Comment: If you really want a variant with a char then pass the short byval and a variant byref to this function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-varui1fromi2. (or a string with one char to the function above it).

Answer (score -1):

*(a) Is there a different VarType() in .Net than in Office?*

No they are identical. They are specified in the Automation library. **It reads the byte in the variant's header**. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant.

*(b) What is vbChar?*

A C concept that makes up a C String which is an array of vbchar (called a char in C). VB6/VBA6/VBA7 doesn't use C strings. Although a C String is contained in a B String. When you pass a string `ByRef` rather than `ByVal` you are passing the address of the contained C String rather than the address of the B String.

What does this mean. A VB programmer will use `Instr()` to acces the nth element. This is a slow function call. It requires the stack to be set up. A C programmer will go `Array(n)` to do the same thing. This is quicker because it is read `baseofarray + (nthelement * 32 bit)`.

*Does the constant vbChar exist? If so, what is it? Is it documented?*

It exists as a number. It is an element of a C String. It is documented in the Automation libraries.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum

If you run `VarType()` on a VBChar is will return the number at that link.

Perhaps you should read VBA (the language of the forms package/compiler VB6) before asking questions. You may get this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/d5418146-0bd2-45eb-9c7a-fd9502722c74

---

**Edit**

---

**Here is your `char` in VB6/VBA**.

```
Declare Function VarI1FromI4 Lib "Oleaut32" (ByVal Code As Byte, ByRef Char As Variant) As Long

Sub Main()
    Dim Code As Byte
    Dim Char
    Dim HResult As Long

    Code = 65
    HResult = VarI1FromI4(Code, Char)
    MsgBox HResult
    MsgBox VarType(Char)

End Sub
```

Note when you step through this code the tooltip on `char` tells you it an *automation type not supported in VB*.

When you try to use it in the `MsgBox` it is auto converted by the Automation library to what ever the function definitions says it wants.

VC++6 and VB6 are wrappers around the automation libraries.

Comment: In your first link, there is no mention of a function `VarType()`. There is a structure member `VARTYPE`, but no function. I was asking about the function `VarType()`.

Comment: You say that your second link documents `vbChar`. In the page at that link, the only occurrences of the string "char" are in the descriptions of `VT_I1` and `VT_UI1`. Is that what you meant? If so, could you explain the relationship of those constants to `vbChar`?

Comment: Your third link is interesting. I'll spend some time with that. But, as you say, it's about VBA. Do you have corresponding reference on VB.net?

Comment: 1. VarType reads the type from the variant's header. Whatever the number in the header VarType will report. 2. How many times times do I have to say this. C Strings are an array of chars. Vb uses B Strings. 3. It fully documented in the .NET Library Framework and the VB language reference. VB.Net documentation is a different style to VBA. In VBA you are only told the minimum you need to know so the contract will work in the future, ie no implementation details.